# How can I generate the image without the diagonal line in an efficient way

Tags: graphics, rendering, textures

The purpose is to generate a square texture image from a triangle patch of the original texture image.

```
tex = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzV5S.png"];
img=Graphics[{Texture[tex],EdgeForm[{}],Polygon[{1-{{0,0},{1,0}, 
{1,1}}},VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0.`,0.`},{1.`,0.`},{1.`,1.`}}]}];
ImageMultiply[img,ImageRotate[img,-180Degree]]
```

There is a white diagonal line which is not needed.

[image: my attempt]

If we add `ImagePadding -> None` option, there is a gray diagonal line.

```
img=Graphics[{Texture[tex],EdgeForm[{}],Polygon[{1-{{0,0},{1,0}, 
{1,1}}},VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0.`,0.`},{1.`,0.`},{1.`,1.`}}]},ImagePadding->None];
ImageMultiply[img,ImageRotate[img,-180Degree]]
```

[image: another attempt]

Comment: But where is `tex`?

Comment: @J.M. added it!

Comment: `PlotRangePadding` still can not work. What a pity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about skipping the ImageMultiply and apply the texture simultaneously to two polygons?

```
img = 
  Graphics[
    {Texture[tex], 
     Polygon[{{{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: great, simple and direct,